# Facebook API "post_video_views" returns value far less than what you see in browser

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video

I make a GET request for a video post on facebook to see how many times the video has been viewed (e.g., "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{userid_postid}/insights/post_video_views?period=lifetime&access_token={access_token}") and this returns a value of 15k. However, if I visit the webpage itself (e.g., https://www.facebook.com/{userid_postid}), I see "60k Views" just below the video frame.

I apologize for my ignorance, but how can I access the 60k value through the API?

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/insights

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to returning the 60k number in the example above: "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{**video_id**}/**video_**insights/**total**_video_views?period=lifetime&access_token={access_token}"

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/video_insights/

Comment: Do you know why the "video_id/video_insights/total_video_views" metric was returning 60K, whereas the "postid/insights/post_video_views" was only returning 15K?

Comment: For reference, I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67203557/what-is-difference-between-the-facebook-api-insights-post-video-views-and-tot) asking why the metrics returned different values. Basically, the same video could be used in multiple posts, so the metric, “total_video_views”, will provide the overall views for the video. Whereas “post_video_views” only gives the views for the specific post.