# What is difference between the Facebook API Insights "post_video_views" and "total_video_views" metrics?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Both of these are metrics used on a video for a page. How you fetch these metrics is slightly different.

So both of these are used to show *"The number of times your videos played for at least 3 seconds..."*. Additionally, these both are returning the same value for all my videos.

What I am interested in knowing is what makes these different? Which one should I use?

Comment: The same video could be used in multiple posts, so one of those metrics gives you the views for a specific post, and the other the overall views for the video.

Comment: Thank you. After messing around with Facebook's UI I did see there is a means to create a new post from an already uploaded video. Thus the metric, “total_video_views”, as you stated will provide the overall views for the video. Whereas “post_video_views” only gives the views for the specific post. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same video could be used in multiple posts - a video uploaded once, can be used as source for new video posts, instead of uploading a completely new one.

So `post_video_views` gives you the views of that video as part of a specific post, and `total_video_views` the overall views for the video.

> Additionally, these both are returning the same value for all my videos.

Yes, if you didn’t use any of those videos multiple times, then both metrics will be the same.